# Wordpress - Write <?php ?> inside echo -html text box

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I need to retrieve the meta value from db to the custom meta box I've created.

Here is my code.

```
 function wpl_owt_book_function( $book ) {

    define("_FILE_", "_FILE_");

    wp_nonce_field( basename(_FILE_), "wp_owt_cpt_nonce");

    echo "<label for='txtPublisherName'>Publisher Name</label>";
    $publisher_name = get_post_meta($post->ID, "book_publisher_name" , true);
    echo "<input type ='text' name = 'txtPublisherName' value = '<?php $publisher_name; ?>' placeholder = 'Publisher Name' />";
}
```

The result output from the text box makes place holder as `<?php` and outside the text box `") placeholder = 'Publisher Name' />"`

Can anyone look into this matter and give me a solution please!

Have a great day!

Comment: Your last echo won't echo what you expect. You can't have opening and closing PHP tags inside an echo (which already is inside php tags). To concatenate a variable in a string, use: `echo "something " . $foo . " something";`.

Comment: Hi Magnus, Thanks for your quick response. Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: I added an example to the comment. I would also recommend reading up about how to use [strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php). This is one of those "PHP 101" knowledge you need to know.

Answer (score 2):

You are already in PHP, so change this:

```
echo "<input type ='text' name = 'txtPublisherName' value = '<?php $publisher_name; ?>' placeholder = 'Publisher Name' />";
```

To this! (removing PHP tags)

```
echo "<input type ='text' name = 'txtPublisherName' value = '" . $publisher_name . "' placeholder = 'Publisher Name' />";
```

Comment: Hi Magnus. Thanks for your generous reply. I replaced it with your code. But the meta value hasn't retrieved to text box

Comment: Shouldn't `$post->ID` be `$book->ID` ? $post is not defined anywhere

Comment: Thanks Mate!. It worked. I changed $book into $post

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace $post->ID with get_the_ID(). so, replace

`get_post_meta($post->ID, "book_publisher_name" , true);`

with

`get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "book_publisher_name" , true);`

and also replace

```
echo "<input type ='text' name = 'txtPublisherName' value = '<?php $publisher_name; ?>' placeholder = 'Publisher Name' />";
```

with

```
echo "<input type ='text' name = 'txtPublisherName' value = '".$publisher_name."' placeholder = 'Publisher Name' />";
```